# Imacro search text

Tags: search, imacros

I have five types of text (example: abc, def, adds, ss aaa, ffff ss). if one of the text in found then cont. with the remaining steps.

Can anyone help me on this. I need the code for imacro

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"(abc|def|adds|ss aaa|ffff ss)"
```

Comment: i will try.... but my question is... if "abc" text is found then i have run set of commands (select set of radio button based on the text)..... if "def" text is found another set of commands.... Will the above mentioned will work.... Pls help me on this

Comment: If text "abc" is found i will be selecting 1, 2, 4 radio button..... if "def" found i will be selecting 2,5, 7 radio button.....